# Python type hinting for constructors in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, settings

In VS Code, whenever I write a constructor for a Python class it appends the type hint "-> None" to it when autocompleting the method.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Is there a setting that configures that behaviour or is there a way to disable it? I would like it to look like the following for constructors:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: the -> None declares the type of the returning value.
because its a constructor there should not be a returning value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to just change the lsp's builtin snippets but VS Code makes it very easy to create your own snippets and you can create your own snippet for a constructor without an explicit return type hint if you want

This page shows hot to do so
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Example snippet for this case

```json
{
  "init": {
    "prefix": ["init", "__init__"],
    "body": [
      "def __init__(self):", 
      "\t$0"
    ],
    "description": "An empty Constructor with no type hints"
  }
}
```